# Make multiple splits in CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it was possible to use CSS grids to do intermediate splits in columns, is this doable? Below a graphical example. 
Thank you very much.

[image: Grid with no multiple splits][image: Wanted splits]

EDIT: I am using display: grid, what I am trying to achieve is something responsive that would put each cell under each other on a mobile device.

[image]

Comment: Yes, everything is possible. E.g. `Column 1/Row 3` can span 2 rows. About what kind of css grid you are talking? `display: grid`/bootstrap grid/table grid...?

Comment: I am using display: grid, I will edit the question to explain what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I just created the example you need but try to make sure that you assign proper names (instead of col-x or row-y) like `navigation` or `sidebar` for example.

I'd recommend to just double the amount of rows and assign the amount of rows twice for the left column. Especially take a look at `grid-template-areas` in the `.grid` CSS.

To change the way the grid looks on smaller devices you can apply `@media` queries on the .grid class to adjust the `grid-*` attributes.

This sample below is not the shortest nor the smartest solution for that but it's the most visual i guess.

```css
.grid {
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80% auto;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 
    "col-1-row-1 col-2-row-1-1"
    "col-1-row-1 col-2-row-1-2"
    "col-1-row-2 col-2-row-2-1"
    "col-1-row-2 col-2-row-2-2"
    "col-1-row-3 col-2-row-3-1"
    "col-1-row-3 col-2-row-3-2"
}

.col-1-row-1,
.col-1-row-2,
.col-1-row-3,
.col-2-row-1-1,
.col-2-row-1-2,
.col-2-row-2-1,
.col-2-row-2-2,
.col-2-row-3-1,
.col-2-row-3-2 {
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
}

.col-1-row-1 {
  grid-area: col-1-row-1;
}
.col-1-row-2 {
  grid-area: col-1-row-2;
}
.col-1-row-3 {
  grid-area: col-1-row-3;
}
.col-2-row-1-1 {
  grid-area: col-2-row-1-1;
}
.col-2-row-1-2 {
  grid-area: col-2-row-1-2;
}
.col-2-row-2-1 {
  grid-area: col-2-row-2-1;
}
.col-2-row-2-2 {
  grid-area: col-2-row-2-2;
}
.col-2-row-3-1 {
  grid-area: col-2-row-3-1;
}
.col-2-row-3-2 {
  grid-area: col-2-row-3-2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-row-1">Col 1 Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-1-row-2">Col 1 Row 2</div>
    <div class="col-1-row-3">Col 1 Row 3</div>
    <div class="col-2-row-1-1">Col 2 Row 1.1</div>
    <div class="col-2-row-1-2">Col 2 Row 1.2</div>
    <div class="col-2-row-2-1">Col 2 Row 2.1</div>
    <div class="col-2-row-2-2">Col 2 Row 2.2</div>
    <div class="col-2-row-3-1">Col 2 Row 3.1</div>
    <div class="col-2-row-3-2">Col 2 Row 3.2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set a new html element below (for example) column2/row1 and set the style as `display: grid; grid-template: auto/auto; align-self: center`